# How to create an empty list in a class, do I need to use the __init__ function is this problem?

Tags: python, class, init

I have a question about my code, do I need to use the '**init**' function in this problem? I tried to use it but I don't know where I went wrong.

Here is the assignment of University Ghent Belgium

"A sequence of items can be sorted in increasing order using a technique that is inspired by the Patience card game. Sorting is done in two phases. First, the items are placed one by one in a series of stacks according to these rules:

initially there are no stacks

the first item forms a new stack that only contains the item

each subsequent item  is placed on the leftmost stack whose top item is greater than or equal to item ; if all top items are smaller than item , the item forms a new stack to the right of all existing stacks

When there are no more items to be placed, the sorted sequence is recovered by repeatedly picking off the smallest visible item. The visible items are the items on top of the stacks.

For instance, consider sorting the integer sequence (4 3 9 1 5 2 7 8 6) using the Patience sorting technique. The first stack gets 4 and 3. Since 9 is larger than 3, it starts a second stack, 1 goes on the first stack, then 5 and 2 go on the second stack. At this point the first stack (top to bottom) consists of (1 3 4), the second stack consists of (2 5 9), and the remaining sequence consists of the integers (7 8 6). Now 7 goes on a third stack, 8 goes on a fourth stack, and 6 goes on top of the 7 in the third stack. With all the items placed, 1 is collected from the first stack, 2 from the second stack, 3 and 4 from the first stack, 5 from the second stack, 6 and 7 from the third stack, 8 from the fourth stack and 9 from the second stack."

ASSIGNMENT

An item is represented as an integer (int). A stack of items is represented as a list (list), where the first element is the item on top of the stack and the last element is the item at the bottom of the stack. A series of stacks that are next to each other is represented as a list (list), where the first element is the leftmost stack and the last element is the rightmost stack.

Define a class PatienceSorter that can be used to sort a sequence of items in increasing order using the Patience sorting technique. The class must support at least the following methods:

A method stacks that returns the current series of stacks (list).

A method stack_count that returns the current number of stacks (int).

A method item_count that returns the current number of items in all stacks (int).

A method add_item that takes an item. The given item must be placed on top of an existing or new stack according to the rules of the Patience sorting technique. The method must return a reference to the object on which the method was called.

A method add_items that takes a sequence (a list (list) or a tuple (tuple)) of items. The given items must be placed one by one on top of an existing or new stack according to the rules of the Patience sorting technique. The method must return a reference to the object on which the method was called.

I have tried to use the **init** function but something is wrong
If I run the program I get:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stacks'

```py
class PatienceSorter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stapel = []

    def stacks(self):
        return self.stapel

    def stack_count(self):
        return len(self.stacks())

    def item_count(self):
        aantal = 0
        for item in self.stacks():
            aantal += len(item)
        return aantal

    def add_item(self, item):
        if self.stack_count() == 0:
            self.stacks().append(item)
        else:
            toegevoegd = False
            for object in self.stacks():
                toegevoegd = False
                laatste = object[len(object) - 1]
                if laatste > item:
                    object.append(item)
                    toegevoegd = True
            if not toegevoegd:
                self.stacks().append(item)
            return self.stacks()
```

[This is what I get when I run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOKT0.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "Use the init function?"  You should create an object by doing something like `my_object = PatienceSorter()`, which will call the constructor (the init function) for you.  Can you give a stack trace?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I edited my post with a picture of when I run the program

Comment: Please post the error/traceback as actual text, not an image.

Comment: You are trying to access the non-existent stacks method of the return value from your add_item call.  You use ```myclass.add_item().stacks()```, but you should just use ```myclass.add_item()``` and then call ```myclass.stacks()``` using the instance of your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that the add_item method only returns when `self.stack_count() != 0`.  If `self.stack_count() == 0`, the method appends the item to `self.stacks()` and then returns None.  Thus, you end up calling `None.stacks()`, resulting in the error.

Also, you said that "The method must return a reference to the object on which the method was called."  In this case, the object is `self`, so you should return `self`, not `self.stacks()`.

Changing your return statement to `self` and fixing the indentation such that it gets called regardless of `self.stack_count()` should prevent the error.  I can't speak to the accuracy of the algorithm, however, as I didn't look at it.

```
def add_item(self, item):
        if self.stack_count() == 0:
            self.stacks().append(item)
        else:
            toegevoegd = False
            for object in self.stacks():
                toegevoegd = False
                laatste = object[len(object) - 1]
                if laatste > item:
                    object.append(item)
                    toegevoegd = True
            if not toegevoegd:
                self.stacks().append(item)
        return self
```

I think stack overflow has a policy against adding screenshots of code, so make sure to include the screenshot in a text format next time.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now, yes I will provide text next time didn't know. And the algorithm, I will check it later it is just understanding the __init__ and classes in python.

Answer (score 0):

There is still an error in the code:

```
self.stacks().append(item)
```

This line appends the item to the list of stacks. When it should actually append a new list containing that item. That is the code should be:

```
self.stacks().append([item])
```

The function should be:

```
 def add_item(self, item):
    if self.stack_count() == 0:
        self.stacks().append([item])
    else:
        toegevoegd = False
        for stack in self.stacks():
            toegevoegd = False
            laatste = stack[-1]
            if laatste > item:
                stack.append(item)
                toegevoegd = True
        if not toegevoegd:
            self.stacks().append([item])
    return self
```

The Boolean variable can be eliminated if you are allowed early return:

```
 def add_item(self, item):

    if self.stack_count() == 0:
        self.stacks().append([item])
    else:
        for stack in self.stacks():
            laatste = stack[-1]
            if laatste > item:
                stack.append(item)
                return self

        self.stacks().append([item])

    return self
```